# Lost supplementary user groups for GUI login session

Tags: lightdm, users, systemd, session, groups

Ubuntu 16.04.5

Very weird situation - after Xorg crash, now every time when I login into Unity, my user account doesn't have it's system groups like `adm`, `sudo`, `plugdev`, `fuse` etc. But when I login on virtual console (Alt+F1) or over SSH - all my additional groups are there, as reported by `id` command.

Neither of `/etc/group*` or `/etc/gshadow*` files have changed, my user is still listed there in many system groups.

It looks like some systemd session parameters for GUI logins or lightdm cache files got screwed. But I have no idea where to start looking..

A lightdm log:

```
$ journalctl -au lightdm

-- Reboot --
systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
lightdm[3223]: pam_kwallet5(lightdm-greeter:setcred): (null): pam_sm_setcred
lightdm[3223]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
lightdm[3345]: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "chm"
lightdm[4867]: pam_ecryptfs: Passphrase file wrapped
lightdm[3345]: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:auth): (null): pam_sm_authenticate
lightdm[3345]: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:setcred): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_setcred
lightdm[3345]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user chm by (uid=0)
lightdm[3046]: Error writing to daemon: Bad file descriptor
lightdm[3046]: Error writing to daemon: Bad file descriptor
lightdm[3046]: Error writing to daemon: Bad file descriptor
lightdm[3046]: Failed to write utmpx: Permission denied
```

Comment: I've seen a number of reports like this recently - can you confirm whether the group memberships are correct if you start a new login shell i.e. `su - $USER` **then** run `id`?

Comment: @steeldriver yes I confirm, group membership is correct for such scenario.

Comment: Maybe you could share `journalctl -au lightdm.service` ?

Comment: Added into the description, but there doesn't seem to be anything "interesting".

Comment: seems to be the same issue as mine and the OPs of this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458194/missing-groups-at-each-startup

Comment: for me a viable workaround for the moment is switching to gdm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a lightdm / kwallet bug, see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1781418 and here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1581495

Commenting out

```
auth optional pam_kwallet.so
auth optional pam_kwallet5.so
```

to

```
#auth optional pam_kwallet.so
#auth optional pam_kwallet5.so
```

in /etc/pam.d/lightdm - as suggested in the link above, solves the problem for now.

Comment: Encountered this problem in a Kubuntu 16.04 install.