# Why `group` does not show new group in GUI bash terminal, when showed in text mode console?

Tags: command-line, permissions, groups

Why after I login in I see user account belonging to newly added group, but in X (GUI desktop after starting with `startx`) in terminal `groups` does not show that group?

Clear reperformance example: Ubuntu 20.04 "standard" iso. Boot with `level 3` boot option added. Get text console.

```
Login: ubuntu
$ sudo addgroup test
$ sudo usermod -a -G test ubuntu
$ exit
Login: ubuntu
$ groups
.... test
$ startx
```

In loaded GUI start terminal

```
$ groups
///no test in the list
$ id
uid=999(ubuntu) ...
```

The only similar issue I see here is [Lost supplementary user groups for GUI login session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059856/lost-supplementary-user-groups-for-gui-login-session) 4 year ago and the reply was "This seems to be a lightdm / kwallet bug".

Added:

Thanks to discussion with @sudodus I've tried to set non-empty password before logout. And that way `groups` within X showed `test`. Why empty password makes a difference? BTW it is boot from live USB iso "disk" I described.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/713371/70524

Comment: uid=999 makes me think it is a live drive. Is that correct? In that case, is it live-only or persistent live? If persistent live, what happens after reboot? If live-only, what happens after logout and login to the desktop? If my guess is wrong, and it is an installed system, what happens after reboot?

Comment: @sudodus. yes, live, I've written to boot Ubuntu iso. I think the way I booted it would not be persistent. . What do you mean "login to the desktop"? I logged in in console and started desktop (X) w/out explicit logins. 
Now trying to check if X would ask for password (which was empty) I set a pass and now with same sequence (except for `sudo pass ubuntu` before `startx`) as in the post `groups` output `test` in GUI ! Do you know why having password mattered?

Comment: I meant logout from the desktop and then login again, which might be 'automatic' when there is no password, but which would wait for your password if a password. I am not sure what was changed by adding a password, maybe there was time for the sequence to modify the settings to recognize your added group. But generally, I have noticed that some settings will not be fully recognized without logout, and some settings need reboot (or shutdown plus boot) to be fully recognized by the system. For this reason, it is more meaningful to modify such settings in installed or persistent live systems.

Comment: @sudodus, from what I know about Linux group membership should be updated upon logout/login. I notice here not all applications for some reason become aware of the change. It looks to me as a bug. But of what? what is responsible of membership information? Kernel? If so, I'm considering filing a bug and see how they respond.

Comment: @sudodus, BTW w/out setting a password, logging out of X and `startx` again resulted in no new group in output in terminal again.

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea to report it as a bug at Launchpad. That is a way to get a dialogue with the developers.

Comment: It is also possible that there was no real logout without setting a password (I am not sure about that, only thinking aloud).

Comment: @sudodus, I have not mentioned it, but before logout `groups` had not listed newgroup, but after - I mentioned it had. So logout/login did resulted in expected result for console even w/out a pass.

Answer (score 1):

Group additions are only applied when you login after the change has been made.  Any existing logins will never see the new group addition.

Comment: Good effort but that I know. how do you explain my example?

Comment: I duplicated what you saw.  What I noticed is that the terminal program was a child of systemd and not a decendant of the login (and startx) processes.  That would explain why those processes didn't pick up the group change.  I don't know why that is the case.  It is certainly not expected behavior.  Perhaps some sort of Unity / Systemd thing.